# How do you display the contents of tags such as tag names and attributes as strings?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, introspection, tagname

Okay, so what I wanted to do was to use DOM introspection to recursively analyze the current state of the DOM and return it as a single, formatted string to be displayed elsewhere.
Either standard DOM functions or JQuery would be sufficient for my purposes.
So far I've tried things like

```
var txt = $("body").tagName;
var txt = $("body").get();
var txt = $("body").nodeName;
var txt = new String($("body").tagName);
```

etc. 
Everytime I try one of these it will either return the node object itself, or undefined.
How do I get it so that I can get a string such as body or < body > returned instead of the object itself?

For that matter, how would I get the name and value of an attribute returned as a string?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`get(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to obtain the original DOM node from a jQuery object if you want to look at it's DOM properties, where `n` is the nth element in the jQuery object.

`nodeName` will get you the name of the node in uppercase, and `getAttribute('attributeName')` or simply `.attributeName` can be used to obtain the value of an attribute.

```
// Contrived example; returns BODY
var n = document.body.nodeName;

// Get the value of an attribute from an element
var n = document.getElementById('id').title;

// Unsupported attribute's value need to be obtained through `getAttribute`
var n = document.getElementById('id').getAttribute('placeholder');
```

Look at this table for a full list of DOM functions and properties: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 1):

To get the tag name you can use: $("body")[0].tagName;

To get the attributes of an element in an object you can use: $("body")[0].attributes; Loop through that object to get the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

`var txt = $("body")[0].tagName;`

**Note**: it'll return the tagName in uppercase lettering.

Comment: "Note: it'll return the tagName in uppercase lettering." Probably.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].tagName` for generic.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery u can get tag of the object like this:

```
var txt = $("body").attr("tagName"); //returns "BODY" (uppercase)
```

For any other attribute insert the attribute's name:

```
var txt = $("div").attr("class"); //returns class of the div
var txt = $("a").attr("title"); //returns title of the anchor
```

Here is the documentation for .attr() method: http://api.jquery.com/attr/